# nvcc fatal : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH although Visual Studio 12.0 is added to PATH

Tags: cuda, nvidia, theano, keras

I have followed all the instructions from https://datanoord.com/2016/02/01/setup-a-deep-learning-environment-on-windows-theano-keras-with-gpu-enabled/
but can't seem to get it work.

I have added 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
to my PATH variable

Every time I run the code from the Theano website to test whether a CPU or GPU is used, it gives me a fatal error of 
"nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH"

Here is the code I use to test:

```
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide the full error message including the traceback. Else, it is very hard to identify and solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I'm using 64 bit Windows 8.1 and I had to add the following to my path and now it works fine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The Visual Studio 2017 has it here

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the argument -ccbin to set where cl.exe is. It will look like this

```
nvcc "File path" -ccbin "cl.exe path"
```